# the app references non-public selectors in Payload determineAppInstallationAttributionWithCompletionHandler:, lookupAdConversionDetails

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, google-analytics, ionic3, cordova-plugins

Ionic 3 and Angular 4 - Used to develop the project. I am using the 'cordova-plugin-google-analytics' plugins for Google Analytics. Validating the ios ipa file facing the warning for

the app references non-public selectors in Payload determineAppInstallationAttributionWithCompletionHandler:, lookupAdConversionDetails".

How to solve this issue?

Comment: It's an issue on GitHub. Have you tried to update firebase. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/8222

Comment: I got the same issue, did you find any solution/workaround? Thanks!